# Simplification of a rational expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

I have been trying to simplify a rational expression; however, I am not able to reach the simplest form of the expression, here is my work:

$$\frac{5g+2}{5g-2}\div\frac{3g-1}{1-3g}$$

Then I try to simplify the equation by first multiplying by its reciprocal

$$\frac{5g+2}{5g-2}\times\frac{1-3g}{3g-1}$$

So once I have multiplication I find a common denominator

$$\frac{(5g+2)(3g-1)}{(5g-2)(3g-1)}\times\frac{(1-3g)(5g-2)}{(3g-1)(5g-2)}$$

However, after I cross out the terms due to division I end up with the same expression at the start

$$\frac{5g+2}{5g-2}\div\frac{3g-1}{1-3g}$$

What step am I missing to simplify it even more?

Comment: I noticed that
$$
\frac{3g-1}{1-3g} = -1.
$$
Is that helpful?

Comment: Could you explain how?

Comment: Because $3g - 1 = - (1 - 3g) = (-1) (1 - 3g)$.  Basically, the numerator and denominator of your 2nd expression are negatives of each other.

Comment: You don't look for a common denominator when multiplying only when adding/substracting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One might wish to note, as mentioned in the comments by @avs, that

$$\frac{3g-1}{1-3g}=\frac{-(1-3g)}{1-3g}=-1$$

Thus, we have

$$\frac{5g+2}{5g-2}\times(-1)$$

Comment: I see it, I am so blind! thanks!

Comment: @pablo No problem!  Your welcome :-P

Comment: Thanks for the acknowledgement to avs. :-)

Comment: @amWhy :-) Thanks for reminding me to put it in.

Answer (score 2):

.The step you are missing is that $-1(1-3g) =  -1 + 3g = 3g-1$, therefore $\frac{3g-1}{1-3g} = -1$! Thank you to avs for the point out in the comments.

Therefore,
$$
\frac{5g+2}{5g-2} \div \frac{3g-1}{1-3g} = \frac{5g+2}{5g-2} \div -1 = \frac{-1(5g+2)}{5g-2} = \frac{-5g-2}{5g-2} 
$$

You can check that:
$$
\frac{-5g-2}{5g-2} = \frac{-4}{5g-2} -1
$$

This simplification puts the expression in "partial sum" form, where only constants are on the numerators.

Comment: "The step you are missing is that $-1(1-3g) =  -1 + 3g = 3g-1$, therefore $\frac{3g-1}{1-3g} = -1$!" **As mentioned in a comment from @avs**

Comment: @amWhy Slow internet. It took me some time to load my answer, when none of the other answers (or comments) had been loaded. I am seeing your comment late as well. I added a further simplification, so my answer gives more "detail" than the comment, for somebody else's help. I would like to ask, how do you write in bold in the comments, because that's not there in the tutorials?

Comment: You use \*\* bold text here \*\*.

Comment: **Thank  you** @SimpleArt

Comment: Actually bold text does't allow spaces between the **.** and the text to boldface.  `**bold text**` will yield **bold text**, whereas  `** bold text **` will yield ** bold text **

Comment: @amWhy Thank you for the comment.